# Stroustrup on comparisons, errata?

Tags: c++

In Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 891, where comparisons properties are described.  He explains that the function `cmp` can be represented by less than `<` for a strict weak ordering.  I'm confused by his explanation of "Transitivity of equivalence" as follows;

> Transitivity of equivalence: Define equiv(x,y) to be
> !(cmp(x,y)||cmp(y,x)). If equiv(x,y) and equiv(y,z), then equiv(x,z).
> The last rule is the one that allows us to define equality (x==y) as !(cmp(x,y)||cmp(y,x)) if we need ==.

Should this instead be defined as follows?

`cmp` is `<=` and `equiv(x,y) = (cmp(x,y) && cmp(y,x))`

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I think the point is that `<=` is not a strict weak ordering but `<` is. So if you have `<` already (because you need a strict weak ordering) then it's easy to define `==` as described.

Comment: `<=` is non-strict yes.  I don't see how his definition of `equiv` is correct with strict weak ordering `<`.

Comment: It's correct, there are three possibilities, less than, equal, and greater than. `!(cmp(x,y)||cmp(y,x))` says it's not the case that the first or the third are true. Therefore only the second possibility remains.

Comment: @john There are four possibilities, you're missing "incomparable". What OP might be missing is that Stroustrup is only talking about *total* orderings, then (and only then) does 'incomparable' disappear as option.

Comment: @orlp I was certainly assuming a total ordering, I think the OP was too.

Comment: No. Do not think `cmp` is `<` or `<=` relation. It is something more general. `<` is just a special case when you think about numbers. Compered objects can have diffren type of relations. To have expected result of sorting some minimal requirements of comparation must be fulfilled and this is purely mathematical problem.

Comment: @john `!(cmp(x,y)||cmp(y,x))` is false for `<, =, >`.

Comment: @notaorb No it isnt.

Comment: @notaorb E.g. `x=7` `y=7`, `x<y` is false, `y<x` is false, `false || false` is false, `!false` is true.

Comment: @john Ok, I see it now!

Comment: @orlp  **Any** strict weak ordering induces total ordering on the set of equivalence classes defined by the relation `equiv(x,y)=!(cmp(x,y)||cmp(y,x))`. The original SWO doesn't need to be total, and often isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is not errata.

```
equiv(x,y) := !(cmp(x,y)||cmp(y,x))
x := x
y := x

substituting in:
!((x < x) || (x < x))
!((false) || (false))
!(false)
true
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Can** this instead be defined as follows?
>
> `cmp` is `<=` and `equiv(x,y) = (cmp(x,y) && cmp(y,x))`

Yes, that also gives you consistent definitions.

> **Should** this instead be defined as follows?

It isn't better than the definitions we use, so I'd suggest **no**, mostly because there's loads of existing code written for the current definition.

Instead of the current definition of [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)

> ***Compare*** is a set of requirements expected by some of the standard library facilities from the user-provided function object types.
>
> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of a type satisfying *Compare*, when contextually converted to `bool`, yields `true` if the first argument of the call appears before the second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this type, and `false` otherwise.
>
> - For all `a`, `cmp(a,a)==false`
> - If `cmp(a,b)==true` then `cmp(b,a)==false`
> - If `cmp(a,b)==true` and `cmp(b,c)==true` then `cmp(a,c)==true`

It would instead be

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of a type satisfying *Compare*, when contextually converted to `bool`, yields `false` if the first argument of the call appears after the second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this type, and `true` otherwise.
>
> - For all `a`, `cmp(a,a)==true`
> - If `cmp(a,b)==false` then `cmp(b,a)==true`
> - If `cmp(a,b)==true` and `cmp(b,c)==true` then `cmp(a,c)==true`